# How to compute the conditional probability?

Tags: probability

The problem is as follows: from a bowl containing 5 red, 3 white and 7 blue chips select four at random and without replacement. Compute the conditional probability of 1 red, 0 white and 3 blue chips, given that there are at least 3 blue chips in this sample of four chips. 
If the task was compute the probability of selecting 1 red, 0 white and 3 blue chips it would be ((5C1)*(3C0)*(7C3))/(15C4) but I can't figure out how to solve the problem with the conditional probability. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A$ be the event "$1$ red, $0$ white, $3$ blue," and let $B$ be the event "at least $3$ blue." We want the conditional probability $\Pr(A|B)$, which is $\Pr(A\cap B)/\Pr(B)$. In our particular case $A\cap B=A$, and you have computed $\Pr(A)$.

It remains to compute $\Pr(B)$, the probability of exactly $3$ blue plus the probability of of exactly $4$ blue. I expect you can compute these.

Comment: You are welcome.